# multiple portlets on a page using rich faces tags

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, portlet

I have created several JSF 2.0 portlets in websphere portal. I am using richfaces tags in my view. I have an issue when more than one portlet use a richfaces tag, such as, `<rich:select...>`, and I try to interact with the rich tag in the FIRST portlet on the portal page, then I keep accumulating js errors like, "too much recursion".

If I interact with the richfaces tag in the second portlet, no js errors. If I remove the second portlet from the page, and simply leave one portlet on the page, everything works great in the first one. If I add multiple rich tags in ONE portlet, everything works great.

Issue is when there are multiple portlets on a page, all portlets have rich tags, and interaction with the rich tags in the first portlet causes js errors.

I am using Rich Faces 4.3.4.

Does this issue sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: In interaction you mean ajax - execute/render of components?